# Double integral on a 2D rotated area : $\iint_D (x+y)^3 (x-y)^2 \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I was assigned an exercise in which I have to calculate a double integral of a given function, in an area which is made from four lines. $D$ is defined by the relations: $x+y=1$ , $x-y=1$ , $x+y=3$ , $x-y=-1$ . The integral is $$\iint\limits_D (x+y)^3 \cdot (x-y)^2 \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$
I came to the conclusion that the lines form a rotated square, with edges the points $A(0,1)$ $B(1,2)$ $C(2,1)$ $D(1,0)$.

[image]

I guess my last step is to calculate the double integral in that area.
 My problem is, can I split the rotated square in 2 isosceles' triangles with points $ABC$, $ADC$ and sum those double integrals together, for more ease? If so, do I have to mention a theorem of some sort that I can't remember?
Is there another way to calculate the double integral on that area?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sure. Variable change $u=x+y,\,v=x-y$ suffice. Don't forget to multiply by Jacobian.

Comment: Updated the question to show the double integral. My only worry at this point is how to handle the square region. What do you mean by variable change at this point? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how to answer the question what do I mean by a coordinate change. Consider this [wiki/Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant) or a book about multivariable calculus. Thanks.

Comment: I know that I can use the coordinate change to simplify an integral, but that does not answer my main question. The topic in question is if I am able to split the square region in which D is defined into 2 triangles to perform the integration on them and then sum the values, and if I need to mention a theorem that allows me to make that split and sum. Thanks again for the answer and the mention on the Jacobian Matrix!

Comment: Yes you can. You can always split an integral such a way i.e. if $D$ is the region where you integrate in and you split it into two disjoint sets $D_1$ and $D_2$ then $$\iint_D=\iint_{D_1}+\iint_{D_2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, brute-forcing without a transformation we have
$$
\iint_D (x+y)^3(x-y)^2\,dxdy 
$$
$$
= \int_0^1\int_{1-y}^{y+1}(x+y)^3(x-y)^2\,dxdy +  \int_1^2\int_{y-1}^{3-y}(x+y)^3(x-y)^2\,dxdy
$$
$$
\stackrel{\text{power rule}}{=} 
$$
$$\frac{2}{15}\left(\int_0^1 8 y^6 + 20 y^3 + 15 y^2 + 15y\, dy + \int_1^2-8 y^6 + 20 y^3 + 585 y^2 - 1449 y + 910\,dy\right)
$$
$$
\stackrel{\text{power rule}}{=}\frac{87}{35}+\frac{439}{105} = \frac{20}{3}
$$On the other hand, using the substitution $u=x+y,v=x-y$, whose Jacobian is $2$, we have
$$
\iint_D (x+y)^3(x-y)^2\,dxdy 
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2} \int _1^3 \int _{-1}^{1} u^3 v^2 \,dvdu = \frac{20}{3}
$$

Comment: I worked my way to this point, except the part which I put a minus on the integral from 0 to 1! Thank you for correcting and writting this so elegantly!